# Restore Database from one Azure Container to another

Tags: sql, azure

How to restore database from one azure container to another one. I have all credentials to both of them and restoring database for one container works, but transfering between two -  not.
I am using that code:

```
RESTORE DATABASE TableName
 FROM URL = 'azure container1/tablename.bak'
 WITH CREDENTIAL = 'ProductionBackupCredential', REPLACE, 
 Move 'TableName' TO 'azure container2/sqldata/tablename.mdf',   
 MOVE 'TableName_log' TO 'azure container2/sqldata/tablename.ldf',Credential = 'StagingBackupCredential';
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
  use master
     ALTER DATABASE tablename SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
     RESTORE DATABASE tablename 
     FROM URL = 'https://azurestorage/tablename.bak'
     WITH 
     CREDENTIAL = 'ProductionBackupCredential',
     REPLACE, 
     Move 'tablename ' TO 'https://azurecontainer2/tablename.mdf',   
     MOVE 'tablename _log' TO 'https://azurecontainer2/tablename.ldf',

      NOUNLOAD, Recovery, STATS = 10
     ALTER DATABASE tablename SET MULTI_USER
     go
```